# Creating a folder from a space template via REST API

Tags: rest, alfresco, openbravo

Well, I formuled this cuestion before but seems like I didnt do correctly, so I will try again explaining myself better.

Im working on a event handler in openbravo that creates a structure of folders via rest api, I have been able to make a single folder so I could make the structure via java but i need to add alot of stuff to all the folders idividually so my work will be x100 harder, so Im searching on internet a way of creating from a space template but cant find nothing, would be nice if u could lend me a hand, its my first time using Rest apis too so Im not that good on this, thx for ur time.

Answer (score 2):

Something cool about Alfresco is that if you look at the [Alfresco public REST API](https://api-explorer.alfresco.com) and you don't see what you are looking for you can simply write your own RESTful end point.

To do that, you use the Web Script Framework ([tutorial](https://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/webscripts/tutorial/tutorial.html)). With the web script framework you can implement controllers using either server-side JavaScript or Java.

That gives you access to the entire foundational API of Alfresco, which includes the ability to create folders from space templates.

For example, when using Java to create a folder from a space template, you can use the fileFolderService to copy the template folder to a parent folder, like this:

```
fileFolderService.copy(template, parentFolder, folderName).getNodeRef();
```

That template variable is a nodeRef. How you get that nodeRef is up to you. One way would be to do a search for it.

So, to re-cap, write a web script. The web script can use the foundational API to create a folder from a template. Your web script can accept arguments for things like where to put the new folder, what space template to use, etc. That's up to you.

Comment: Since im not using any library of alfresco in my openbravo project I just cant do that, should I install something to use alfresco methods(If u can tell me where to download the library would be nice)? or maybe getting the node via RestApi and then making a copy with /nodes/{nodeId}/children is they way of making it with RestApi

Comment: If you don't have access to the Alfresco installation in order to deploy a web script then you will not have access to the foundation API and you will have to use either the REST API or CMIS. Getting the node via the REST API and making a copy should work.